# Should I take an argument as an inheritance object?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

So I came across an idea that I have been mulling about. I'm suspicious about it but it works so I was wondering if anyone has any experience working with something like this:

```
def make_new_class(Koola,Booba):

    class Bar(Koola,Booba):
        def __init__(self):
            Koola.__init__(self)
            Booba.__init__(self)

    return Bar
```

Where Koola and Booba are other classes.

So this actually works. But have found very little talking about this possibility.

Is it good practice? If not what are the alternatives?

If you are curious of where this might turn up; This might come up in situations where you want a class that inherits from a variety of subclasses.  Maybe you have a bunch of algorithms that do the same thing in different ways and you want to stick them together like legos.

Comment: Hi! Did you mean `return Bar`?

Comment: @Montreal yep! :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. Class decorators are another example of callables that return classes. There is little talking about that, simply because (except for decorators) this concept has little use cases. But if is makes sense for you, because you want to dynamically inherit bases classes that require initialisation, you can use it. If the base classes do not require initialisation, simple inheritance would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question!

Classes are first-class citizen in python, so any manipulation with them is as good as manipulation with any other object. But multiple inheritance is quite nasty thing and should be avoided at all, if possible.

Be aware of this:

```
class A1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class A2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2

Composed1 = compose(A1, A2)
c1 = Composed1()
print(c1.a)   # prints 2

Composed2 = compose(A2, A1)
c2 = Composed2()
print(c2.a)   # prints 1
```

And this is the most obvious caveat. There are many others.

Ye be warned.